# IOException using joda-time in non-Android project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jodatime

I've created a simple Java + Gradle project in IntelliJ IDEA to test `joda-time` library functionality. It's *NOT* an Android project, so the **answers from other related issues don't work**, because they suggest solutiouns for Android projects. Hence, this question is not a duplicate, please read carefully.

I'm getting the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Resource not found: "org/joda/time/tz/data/ZoneInfoMap" ClassLoader: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@277050dc
    at org.joda.time.tz.ZoneInfoProvider.openResource(ZoneInfoProvider.java:225)
    ...
```

All I did is added the librarly dependency in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile "joda-time:joda-time:2.10:no-tzdb"
}
```

Comment: What if you get rid of the `no-tzdb` classifier?

Comment: @Slaw - yeah, that works. You can write an answer, so I approve it, if you want.

Comment: My comment was a hunch. The error indicated the timezone information was missing and the `no-tzdb` would seem to stand for "no timezone database". I would need to find documentation for me to be confident in posting an answer. Though to be honest I don't feel like looking for documentation at the moment. However, if you find documentation I have no problem with you posting an answer yourself.